# How do I use jQuery to access this element?

Tags: jquery

If the html is:

```
<div>
 <span class="fNotesTitle">Notes: </span>
 <span class="fNotes">test</span>
</div>
<div class="editNotesBTN">Edit Notes</div>
```

and my jQuery listener was triggered by clicking a button with the editNotesBTN class, how do I access the text (test) in the fNotes class please?

I thought

```
$(this).parent().prev('.fNotes').text();
```

would do it, but it and other combinations aren't working.

The listener's working ok, as I can access an element that follows the editNotesBTN class.

Thank you

Comment: `$(this).prev().find('.fNotes').text()`

Comment: Thank you Graficode - that did it. So do you always need to use find? eg I can access an element after the above html using $(this).parent().next('.z').attr("id");

Comment: `.find` is for looking *in* the current element - if it's a sibling, then don't use `find`

Comment: you first access the previous element using `prev()`, which gives you the `div` (spans wrapper). then you use `find()` to access that element's children.